# vs code cannot launch android emulator

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, sdk, android-emulator, flutter-test

i was just starting with flutter and i was using android studio before and i have an emulator but now i wanted to start with flutter and tried to run the default flutter project but says no device and when i try to connect to the emulator i have it just keeps loading and says "Failed to launch Pixel 3a API 29: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds"
tried a lot to fix it but still the same error.
and by the way when i run `flutter doctor`it displays
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
1.[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
2.[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
✗ Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
3.[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
4.[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
5.[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before, Try these steps:

- Open your android studio, go to avd manager

  Now select your emulator, click on dropdown in actions and wipe data
- Check whether you have intel x86 emulator accelerator ticked in sdk tools in android studio.

If the problem still persists, you can remove this emulator and install a new one.